# Creating Virtual Device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have already installed SDK Packages but there is no system image when I create a new virtual device for android development. What do I need to install? Is there any configuration for virtual device setUp? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android Studio go to

Tools-->Android---->AVDManager then click create new virtual device

[image]

you can select the device based on model and api level

if its not already downloaded means you have to click download 
[image]

Then click next and  configure the setting (default setting have some values if you want you can change it)

Then click ok.

Now your emulator added.

when you run/debug  project you can select your Device in select deployment target popup

[image]

Comment: After clicking Next button, IDE makes me to choose System Image. But there is nothing to choose and Finish button is not clickable. Anyway thanks to you. :D

Comment: if its not already downloaded means you have to click download that image.